# C# NativeWebSocket. OnMessage does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket

In general, I have such a problem. There is no way to get a response from the Kucoin server over a socket connection using NativeWebSocket. There are no errors. The socket connection is successfully opened, but then silence... I don't get any market data in response. I don't know what else he needs. Chatgpt is also powerless ... Wrote in support of kucoin and here. Maybe someone else has had this problem before and can help...

[Kucoin documentation](https://docs.kucoin.com/#websocket-feed)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using NativeWebSocket; // I'm using this technilogy, because i dev a mobile app.
using System;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;

public class WebSocketHistory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WebSocket websocket;
    private Coroutine pingCoroutine; // Coroutine for the ping
    private int pingInterval; // Interval for the ping
    public IEnumerator Connect() {
        // Sending http request to became a token and a endPoint for the websocket connection:
        yield return StartCoroutine(AuthRequest("https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/bullet-public", "{}")); // It works well.. Let's move on to AuthRequest Coroutine.
    }

    private IEnumerator Subscribe() {
        Debug.Log("Subscribe"); // this log is output succesfully
        yield return websocket.SendText("{\"id\":\"trade\",\"type\":\"subscribe\",\"topic\":\"/market/match:" + DataStatic.symbol + "\",\"privateChannel\":false,\"response\":true}");
        // I also tried to do it, it's an old version in my opinion(same result):
        //yield return websocket.SendText("{\"type\":\"subscribe\",\"topic\":\"/market/match:" + DataStatic.symbol + "\"}");

        if(pingCoroutine != null) StopCoroutine(pingCoroutine);
        pingCoroutine = StartCoroutine(PingPong()); // Starting Coroutine PingPong
        Debug.Log("Subscribed"); // and this log is output succesfully too
    }

    private IEnumerator PingPong() { // It method-coroutine works good,
        // but i have no way to check the returned pong from server..
        // Logs (Debug.Log)  are displayed regularly.
        while (true) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds((float)pingInterval / 1000f);
            Debug.Log("Ping");
            yield return websocket.SendText("{\"id\":\"trade\",\"type\":\"ping\"}");
            Debug.Log("Pong");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator Close() {
        yield return websocket.Close();
    }

    public IEnumerator AuthRequest(string url, string postData) {
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, postData)) {
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();
            if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) {
                string response = request.downloadHandler.text;
                TokenAuth tokenAuth = JsonUtility.FromJson<TokenAuth>(response);

                if (tokenAuth.code == "200000") { // Good
                    string token = tokenAuth.data.token;
                    string endPoint = tokenAuth.data.instanceServers[0].endpoint;
                    pingInterval = tokenAuth.data.instanceServers[0].pingInterval;

                    websocket = new WebSocket(endPoint + "?token=" + token + "&[connectId=connectId]");
                    // I also tried it without "&[connectId=connectId]" - same result...
                    
                    websocket.OnOpen += () => {
                        Debug.Log("Connection open!"); // It works.
                        StartCoroutine(Subscribe()); // Go to Subscrive Coroutine...
                    };

                    websocket.OnError += (e) => {
                        Debug.Log("Error: " + e);
                    };

                    websocket.OnClose += (e) => {
                        Debug.Log("Connection closed: " + e.ToString());
                    };

                    websocket.OnMessage += (bytes) => { // It does not work !!!
                        string message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                        Debug.Log(message);
                    };

                    yield return websocket.Connect();
                }
                else {
                    // status error...
                }
            }
            else {
                Debug.Log("Request error: " + request.error);
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class TokenAuth {
        public string code;
        public Data data;
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class Data {
        public string token;
        public InstanceServers[] instanceServers;

    }
    [Serializable]
    public class InstanceServers {
        public string endpoint;
        public bool encrypt;
        public string protocol;
        public int pingInterval;
        public int pingTimeout;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class OJson {
        public int code;
        public OJsonElements[] data;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class OJsonElements {
        public long sequence;
        public double price;
        public double size;
        public string side;
        public long time;
    }
}
```

Purpose of the task: To receive data from the kucoin crypto-exchange over a socket connection, namely data on concluded transactions.

Problem: OnMessage does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially relevant for someone in the future.
Experienced a similar issue, primarily because I overlooked something that looked irrelevant in the example code.

```
void Update()
{
#if !UNITY_WEBGL || UNITY_EDITOR
    websocket.DispatchMessageQueue();
#endif
}
```

Calling DispatchMessageQueue() is required. Receiving a new message will not automatically invoke OnMessage, but add the message to a list. This method will go through this list and invoke OnMessage.